# My login route doesn't work after trying to force SSL via routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I want people to be able to both subscribe and login to my application via SSL. My original route, which was not SSL, was this:

```
resource :login, controller: "sessions" do
  collection do
    get 'new'
    get 'create'
  end
end
```

Worked great, but was unencrypted. Then I tried this:

```
scope :protocol => 'https://', :constraints => { :protocol => 'https://' } do
  resource :login, controller: "sessions" do
    collection do
      get 'new'
      get 'create'
    end
  end
end
```

Now Rails me:

```
No route matches [GET] "/login"
```

when I navigate to `https://myapp.dev/login`

Please note I am using Pow in development mode.

Comment: Anything in this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121671/ssl-with-ruby-on-rails) help?

Comment: And why you add here constraints? This should contains regexp or/and subdomains? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Eraden - Because I copied it from somewhere else and I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, I was thinking it would just be

```
  scope :constraints => { :protocol => "https" } do 
  resource :login, controller: "sessions" do
    collection do
      get 'new'
      get 'create'
    end
   end
 end
```

and you could put more resource entries under there as needed

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you leave the route as is and add in your `production.rb` file:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

This way you will have all the traffic routed via SSL, not only the login controller, which is a good practise to protect your user session cookies.